# Object gets narrower at tight curves when following a path

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm making a racetrack  for karts. I used a path to get the layout of the circuit, then added a shape and used array and curve modifiers to make it follow the path and complete the track. But for some reason it won't stay at the same width the whole way through, and gets really narrow at some points. I've tried for hours scaling and rotating but nothing is working.

[image]

Edit: Added the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: It looks from the shading as if the object you're using to make the road is at right angles to the view rather than flat. Share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that someone can have a look.

Comment: @JohnEason I zoomed in and noticed each rectangle making up the array, instead of rotating to follow the curve, it just become more and more angled until its paper thin. How do I stop that? (the image is a top down view btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Scale) to the NurbsPath - when I did this, I had to  drastically increase the number of cube objects in the array (5000) to make it fill the curve, however, and even still, there's a very small gap where the ends meet:

[image: Path]

Comment: I don't know what he's done to that Nurbs Path, but when I created another one, traced the original with it and then used a plane instead of a cube, it worked perfectly!